# Replacing placeholder name with value in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, multi-module, parent-pom

i am working with multimodule project and i wanted to put placeholder for version in my pom.xml so that our team members can build their own war/jar by using command line, without hardcoding version in parent pom and child poms. Currently the problem is placeholder value is not updated in .m2 folder. please help me to resove this issue.

Comment: Building should be done by a CI solution like Jenkins and not manually ... The war/jar version is vital for identifying a particular state of your development which is usually related to your development via a tag in your version control which is represented by your version in your pom file? To handle the version you should take a deep look into: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the placeholder values inside the pom file, then it can be done by below two commands

```
 mvn versions:set -DnewVersion="2.1.1"
 mvn versions:commit
```

Once done, you can trigger the build using the usual commands `mvn package` or `mvn install`

Comment: This will not work. It will produce not consumable pom file...Apart from that a version `hello` is not a good choice for a version.

Comment: @Shivam Som, i done the same. but in .m2 folder when we see pom, placeholder is not updated with value

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for pointing it out. renamed the version. Ideally, yes versioning should be handled via Release pipelines and it should be an automated process which can be done via tools such as Azure DevOps, Jenkins, etc.

Comment: @Dev updated the answer as per your requirement. This will update the placeholder as well

Comment: @ShivamSom thanks for the update, but actually we have placeholder in our pom. main version we will get it from properties tag, and fixed version we will send through maven command       ex.                                                                  
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId>serv-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${app.version}${subversion}</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>

Comment: <properties><app.version>1.12.0</app.version></properties> mvn clean install -Dsubvesrion=DEV-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

You can put properties in the pom.xml of your top-level project as such:

```xml
<project>
  <!-- other stuff ... -->
  <properties>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    <jdo.version>3.0</jdo.version>
    <datanucleus.version>2.2.1</datanucleus.version>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Then in your module pom.xml you can use a variable reference that will be replaced with the actual value. For example:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
  <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
  <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
</dependency>
```